# Which is the best way to model a low poly coat?

Tags: modeling

i have this 3D model here 
[image]

I want to know which is the best way to model a low poly coat like this one

[image]

Comment: Try for yourself first. If you get into trouble, ask.

Comment: It's strange how an answer with 11 upvotes is useful, but the question who caused it, is not!?

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a nice video: https://www.blendernation.com/2017/05/30/sewing-low-poly-clothes-blender/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For low poly clothes you could start by blocking out the shape with just vertices and edges. Begin with a simple plane delete two vertices, add a mirror modifier and start extruding vertices around your model with <kbd>E</kbd> and connecting vertices with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: Imgur]

Then when you get something like in the picture, you can start connecting those edges and pairs of vertices to make faces around your model using <kbd>F</kbd> in edit mode.

[image: Imgur]

When you get a simple geometry that works you can add loops to refine the model with <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>. Then you can add a solidify modifier and play with the thickness parameter to give volume to the cloth.

For the details as it's a low poly model you'd have to texture them, but you can simplify the process by sculpting first then baking the results and applying a normal map or displacement map to get volume.