# How can you create detailed low poly meshes?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I know this question could be too general and maybe not focused but i would like to have an opinion. I found these images from this link

http://www.zbrushcentral.com/showthread.php?77667-My-work-from-Assassin-s-creed-2-%29

Here an example:
[image]

I assume this is done by zbrush but what's getting me astonished is the vertex number... how can you create such a defined mesh with just 4000/6000 tris??? Is it a matter of 3d modelling program, modelling skill or it is just the texture that's doing all the job? Can i realize these meshes with few vertices using blender?

Comment: Take a look at related qestion about clothes modeling - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6628/which-is-the-best-way-to-model-a-low-poly-coat, about baking normal maps - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24048/create-a-low-poly-mesh-with-high-detailed-textures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do the exact same thing with blender if you know how. Usually from a game asset modeling standpoint, the steps would be...

1. Created the initial model in the highest resolution possible.
2. Retopology. Meaning recreate the model in low poly count.Using surface snaps or retopo tools.
3. Unwrap the low poly mesh, and bake the high poly model's normal onto the low poly model. - affectionately known as "texture baking".

**Note**
The step 3 above enable game artist to fake the amount of mesh details on any given low polygon model. All of todays AAA titles base model details comes from normals map.**

4. Create textures, eg. diffuse, specular map, height map and ambient occlusion map ... etc. ( Using photo texture or hand painted ones. )
5. Export to fbx and import the data into a game engine, eg. Unreal or Unity.

Comment: Thak you very much!! Could you suggest to me a good tutorial about the point 2? Retopology my mesh in the best way . . .  i can't find anyone clear

Comment: Here is the Mira tool addon for blender in action... it's free https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9EILBh4lGQ and this is where you can find the relevant download on blenderartist forum http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?366107-MiraTools

Comment: Thak you so much mate!! Clear and usefull !! God bless you